# "Upgrading" a mechanical defrost timer in an upright "frost free" freezer

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

I am a happy owner of an [upright frost free freezer](http://www.whirlpool.com/-%5BEV161NZTQ%5D-1001287/EV161NZTQ/) which, after only two years, has needed to have its [mechanical defrost timer](http://www.sears.com/whirlpool-defrost-timer-3-81329/p-SPM2647215121) replaced. Apparently, this timer runs the heater coil for twenty minutes after every twelve hours of compressor operation.

I have read some concerns that people have voiced about [short cycling a refrigerant compressor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/what-are-the-rules-for-unplugging-a-refrigerator) and am interested in [cutting costs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/can-i-save-energy-costs-by-turning-off-the-refrigerator-for-1-2-hours-every-day) as well as reducing wear on the machine.

My question is: **are there any controller upgrades that would be more intelligent about running the defrost coil?** For example, a simple, improved rule set would consist of:

```
  IF   time since last last defrost > 12 hours
  AND  positive rise (defrost timer is being energized because thermostat closing)
  THEN start defrost cycle
  ELSE run compressor
```

It strikes me that there might be a drop-in replacement controller that already follows similar logic, which would theoretically greatly reduce the chances of short cycling the compressor when initiating a defrost cycle.

In our usage case, we open and close the freezer at least once a day and try to keep it packed to the gills with pwecious fwood.

Comment: "Short cycling" from the defrost cycle is not a concern here.  The main issue with frost free freezers that I know of is they tend to wreck food more quickly than manual defrost freezers.  The defrost cycle tends to accelerate food freezer burn.

Comment: @chris, thanks for pointing this out. I actually constructed some crude storage bins that are lined with phase change material that freezes at -10 deg F to help keep some of my most precious food from being destroyed as quickly.