# Can i turn off my fridge(refrigerator) at night?

Tags: refrigerator, saving-money

**Question** I use refrigerator just for keeping 2-3 water bottles, 1colddrink bottle, and maximum 0.5 kg of fruits and nothing else (no food items)!

So is it better to off my refrigerator at night and start it in morning? (As i will lost no food) and I think, **I will save some amount of electricity and may be my refrigerator will last longer with me?**

Note: I had purchased new refrigerator and I am from India and tempreture range of my hometown is (24°c - 44°c) in complete year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I save energy costs by turning off the refrigerator for 1-2 hours every day?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/can-i-save-energy-costs-by-turning-off-the-refrigerator-for-1-2-hours-every-day)

Comment: This question has been asked a number of times on the site and the answer is often No. (for more than one reason); but this is not to say it cant. Modern appliances especially with energy star ratings give you a decent cost per year estimate. If you open this fridge once a day your cost is going to be less. If the external temp is too it will also be less. Buy a smaller appliance if no food is stored in it. If you turn it off, when you turn it back on it has to "work harder" to cool to a stat-set-temp. You can measure it to find out, but you might spend more measuring it.

Comment: Ine method to help is to minimise air displacement when opening the door - filling empty space with empty boxes keeps cold air inside.

Comment: Actually, fill the refrigerator to the gills with water bottles. They have a huge amount of thermal "inertia" and will help it coast through the night.   Will also reduce air displacement as Solar Mike describes

Comment: @noybman , no. Partially yes. Because that, question is asked for just 1-2 hour s a day and i am asking it for 7-8 hours a day....

Comment: @noybman  further, i asked something else too, i asked that, does turning off my refrigerator in night, will increase my refrigerator life span?

Comment: I agree with @Harper-ReinstateMonica ... if you fill the refrigerator with water bottles, then it will not run much after all the water is cooled down ... what size is the refrigerator?

Comment: The answer to your variant of the question is the same as the most up-voted answer to the duplicate noybman points to - except that your case is likely to stress your fridge even more due to having to 'catch up' for a lot longer in the morning. Doing this to your fridge is likely to make it run longer on average over a 24-hour period.